# How to parse a date string that contains a non-standard timezone format?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to parse date strings with DateFormat, but I can't get the second format to run.

Sample code:

```
DateTime parsedDate1 = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").parse("2023-10-20 08:29:46 GMT+02:00");
print(parsedDate1);

DateTime parsedDate2 = DateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z yyyy").parse("Wed Oct 25 14:32:49 GMT+02:00 2023");
print(parsedDate2);
```

This results in the following output:

```
FormatException: Trying to read   from Wed Oct 25 14:32:49 GMT+02:00 2023 at 24
```

I'm trying to debug this using DartPad, if that's relevant.

Am I doing something wrong?

Update:
Preprocessing the string so that the year comes earlier and the timezone comes last seems to work. I'm using this format now:
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z

Comment: The [documentation of `DateFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) suggests it doesn't actually implement support for `z`, it is just reserved.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I suspected as much, which is why I was surprised that the first string parsed correctly. My guess is that the first string conforms to a certain standard, and the second string does not. In any case, preprocessing the second results in a correctly parsed DateTime.

Comment: I suspect (but to be clear, I don't write Dart), that it simply stops processing if there is a reserved but not implemented format marker at the end, but in the second one it is in the middle.